# Не запускается ubuntu на другом пк

Tags: ubuntu

Есть жесткий диск на котором была установлена убунту, подключил к другому пк(если быть точнее то к ноутбуку как внешний диск через usb), запустил через биос и черный экран, как его запустить на другом пк?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Загрузчик точно ее подхватил? Что в логах?

Comment: @d4rkm3z,вообще ничего, просто черный экран. Я просто взял жесткий диск с одного пк, вставил в другой и выбрал его через биос

Comment: Сталкивался с такой проблемой, но с Kali Linux. К сожалению помогла только переустановка.

Comment: @DGDays, я могу сохранить все данные?

Comment: 1. Стоит проверить загрузчик - не остался ли он на другом ПК
2. Добавить загрузочную запись